# How do I rotate an arrow to point towards the mouse position on screen

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am trying to add a direction vector to my brick breaker game at the start of each level so that the player can shoot the ball in a specific direction.

I created a new file to draw and update the vector, but I cannot find a way to update it so that it moves with the cursor.

Currently my game will draw the vector in a vertical position. What I want to do is create an event listener that saves the x and y position of the mouse at every update, then rotate the vector based on the angle difference between the vertical vector and the vector to be made using the x and y position of the mouse.

Here is the simple arrow that I draw in the vector file.

```
draw(ctx) {

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.paddleCenter.x, this.paddleCenter.y);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI/ 180 );
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;

    ctx.moveTo( 0, 0 );
    ctx.lineTo( this.pointer.x , this.pointer.y ); 
    ctx.lineTo( this.pointer.x - 10, this.pointer.y + 10);
    ctx.arcTo( this.pointer.x, this.pointer.y, this.pointer.x + 10, this.pointer.y + 10, 20);
    ctx.lineTo( this.pointer.x, this.pointer.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();


}
```

In a separate file I have all my event listeners. I know it should look something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('pointerover', (event) => {

        vector.moveVector(event.clientX, event.clientY);

    })
```

where

```
moveVector(x, y) {

    this.pointer.x = x;
    this.pointer.y = y
}
```

but it doesn't update in the game. I imagine it is because my game update function doesn't redraw the objects in the game until the next level is reached.

What do I need to include in the vector update(deltaTime) function so that the vector moves with the mouse? Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to get it to work?

---

*UPDATE*

I was able to get it working.

In input.js

```
document.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => {

        game.vector.mousePointer.x = event.clientX;
        game.vector.mousePointer.y = event.clientY;

    });
```

In vector.js

```
 update(deltaTime) {

   this.angle = this.moveVector();

}

moveVector() {

 //Calculate angle to rotate vector
 // 0 angle denotes arrow pointing left
 let gameY = this.paddleCenter.y;
 let gameX = this.paddleCenter.x;
 let mouseY = this.mousePointer.y;
 let mouseX = this.mousePointer.x;
 let theta = 0;

 if (this.mousePointer.x < this.paddleCenter.x && this.mousePointer.y < this.paddleCenter.y){
 theta = Math.atan((gameY - mouseY) / (gameX - mouseX)) * 180 / Math.PI; };

else if (this.mousePointer.x > this.paddleCenter.x && this.mousePointer.y < this.paddleCenter.y){
 theta = 180 - Math.atan((gameY - mouseY) / (mouseX - gameX)) * 180 / Math.PI; };

else if (this.mousePointer.x < this.paddleCenter.x && this.mousePointer.y > this.paddleCenter.y ) {
 theta = 0 };

else if (this.mousePointer.x > this.paddleCenter.x && this.mousePointer.y > this.paddleCenter.y) {
 theta = 180 };

return theta 
};
```

However I have more problems that I am currently working on.

I can't get the vector to point just using a pointer over event listener. when I use 'pointerover' the vector points to the direction that my mouse returned on the screen. If I move my mouse on the actual game screen, it doesn't update automatically.

Also, the arrowhead of my drawn vector doesn't rotate. So when I mousedown on screen, the line portion of the vector will rotate to the correct position, but the arrowhead portion remains unrotated.

If you have any suggestions for how to fix these problems I would appreciate it.

Comment: It looks like you're moving the vector to the mouse position rather than rotating it. I see you have an angle variable on this defined, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think about this question, is by considering mouse coordinate as a position vector.

So by getting the angle from the vector, you can either use it to rotate the context, or to draw your pointer based on that angle.

```
var getAngle = function(x, y){
    const angle = Math.atan2(y, x)/Math.PI*180;
    return (360+Math.round(angle))%360; // corrects for angles between 180 ~ 360
}

// you can plug in the mouse coordinate in this
getAngle(-10,10); // returns 135
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure it out:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, html, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
// you can put the following on another page using a load Event - besides the end load
function Arrow(canvasElement, arrowWidth = 25, arrowHeight = 75, lineWidth = 3, strokeStyle = '#000', lineCap = 'round'){
  let bc = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect(), ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
  const w = bc.width, h = bc.height, ha = arrowWidth/2;
  canvasElement.width = w; canvasElement.height = h; ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle; ctx.lineCap = lineCap;
  let x = w/2, hh = h/2, y = hh-arrowHeight/2, hit = false;
  this.clear = ()=>{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }
  const arrowTop = ()=>{
    ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  }
  this.make = ()=>{
    this.clear(); arrowTop(); ctx.lineTo(x, y+arrowHeight); ctx.stroke(); 
    arrowTop(); ctx.lineTo(x-ha, y+ha); ctx.stroke();
    arrowTop(); ctx.lineTo(x+ha, y+ha); ctx.stroke();
    return this;
  }
  this.rotate = deg=>{
    ctx.save(); ctx.translate(x, hh); ctx.rotate(Math.PI/180*deg);
    ctx.translate(-x, -hh); this.make(); ctx.restore();
    return this;
  }
  const hitRotate = e=>{
    if(!hit){
      return;
    }
    bc = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.rotate(90+Math.atan2(e.clientY-bc.top-hh, e.clientX-bc.left-x)*180/Math.PI);
  }
  const hitStart = e=>{
    hit = true; hitRotate(e);
  }
  const hitStop = ()=>{
    hit = false;
  }
  this.touch = ()=>{
    canvasElement.ontouchstart = hitStart;
    canvasElement.ontouchmove = e=>{
      hitRotate(e.touches[0]);
    }
    canvasElement.ontouchend = hitStop;
    return this;
  }
  this.mouse = ()=>{
    canvasElement.onmousedown = hitStart;
    canvasElement.onmousemove = hitRotate;
    canvasElement.onmouseup = canvasElement.onmouseout = hitStop;
    return this;
  }
}
const arrow = new Arrow(I('can'));
arrow.rotate(45);
if(mobile){
  arrow.mobile();
}
else{
  arrow.mouse();
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#ccc;
}
.main{
  padding:10px;
}
#can{
  display:block; width:480px; height:270px; background:#fff; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <canvas id='can'></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS

You can ignore most of the code above the `Arrow` constructor, but keep and reuse it.